# Conda package installs in wrong environment

Tags: software-installation, anaconda, environment, conda

I am trying to install torch using conda however, it installs it into another conda environment not the one I am interested in. How can I fix this?

```
[jalal@goku NAACL2018]$ conda install pytorch torchvision -c pytorch
Solving environment: done

## Package Plan ##

  environment location: /scratch/sjn/anaconda

  added / updated specs: 
    - pytorch
    - torchvision


The following packages will be downloaded:

    package                    |            build
    ---------------------------|-----------------
    pytorch-0.4.1              |py27__9.0.176_7.1.2_2       471.4 MB  pytorch
    openssl-1.0.2p             |       h470a237_1         3.1 MB  conda-forge
    ca-certificates-2018.10.15 |       ha4d7672_0         135 KB  conda-forge
    conda-4.5.11               |        py27_1000         651 KB  conda-forge
    torchvision-0.2.1          |           py27_1         123 KB  pytorch
    ------------------------------------------------------------
                                           Total:       475.4 MB

The following packages will be UPDATED:

    ca-certificates: 2018.8.24-ha4d7672_0 conda-forge --> 2018.10.15-ha4d7672_0       conda-forge
    conda:           4.5.11-py27_0        conda-forge --> 4.5.11-py27_1000            conda-forge
    openssl:         1.0.2p-h470a237_0    conda-forge --> 1.0.2p-h470a237_1           conda-forge
    pytorch:         0.4.0-py27hd73e86b_0             --> 0.4.1-py27__9.0.176_7.1.2_2 pytorch    
    torchvision:     0.2.1-py27_0         conda-forge --> 0.2.1-py27_1                pytorch    

Proceed ([y]/n)? y


Downloading and Extracting Packages
pytorch-0.4.1        | 471.4 MB  | ##################################### | 100% 
openssl-1.0.2p       | 3.1 MB    | ##################################### | 100% 
ca-certificates-2018 | 135 KB    | ##################################### | 100% 
conda-4.5.11         | 651 KB    | ##################################### | 100% 
torchvision-0.2.1    | 123 KB    | ##################################### | 100% 
Preparing transaction: done
Verifying transaction: done
Executing transaction: done
[jalal@goku NAACL2018]$ python 
Python 3.6.4 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)| (default, Jan 16 2018, 18:10:19) 
[GCC 7.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import torch
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torch'
>>> quit()
[jalal@goku NAACL2018]$ conda install pytorch torchvision -c pytorch
Solving environment: done

# All requested packages already installed.

[jalal@goku NAACL2018]$ which conda
/scratch/sjn-p3/anaconda/anaconda3/bin/conda
```

How can I force it to not install it in `environment location: /scratch/sjn/anaconda` ? And I want it to install for the python located in `/scratch/sjn-p3/anaconda/anaconda3/bin/conda`

Comment: This looks off topic for Ubuntu support. Address the question to Anaconda. It is their software.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `-n` or `--name` flag of `conda install` to install into a particular environment.  For example,

```
$ conda install --name myenv pytorch torchvision -c pytorch
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two options, but I note that your two locations are not environments but anaconda installations. When you use environments, that location is in `env/` directory of your installation.

If both are really environments, you can:

- Activate your environment and install

  `conda activate anaconda3`
  `conda install pytorch torchvision -c pytorch`
- Install specifying environment

  `conda install -n anaconda3 pytorch torchvision -c pytorch`